# Node.js Q Promises Multiple Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Trying to cleanup my callback spaghetti code using the Q promise library in my nodejs express app, but I'm having trouble translating some parts of it. Having trouble passing multiple arguments to functions and dealing with the scope.

Here's a simplified "synchronous" version to show my logic:

```
function updateFacebook(req, res) {
    var user = getUserFromDB(userid);
    var profile = getUserProfileFromAPI(accessToken);

    var success = updateUserDB(user, profile);
    res.json({ result: success });
}
```

So I convert the callback functions to return promises

```
function getUserFromDB(userid) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // somewhere in here there's a deferred.resolve(user object);
    queryMongo()...
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getUserProfileFromAPI(accessToken) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // somewhere in here there's a deferred.resolve(profile object);
    request()...
    return deferred.promise;
}

function updateUserDB(user, profile) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // somewhere in here there's a deferred.resolve(updated user object);
    updateMongo()...
    return deferred.promise;
}

function handleResponse(res, user) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    // was thinking about putting the res.json here
    // i have no way of passing in the res
    // and res is out of scope...
    res.json({});

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now the problem is linking them up, I tried...

```
Q.when(getUserFromDB(userid), getUserProfileFromAPI(accessToken))
 .spread(updateUserDB)
 .done(handleResponse);

Q.all([getUserFromDB(userid), getUserProfileFromAPI(accessToken)])
 .spread(updateUserDB)
 .done(handleResponse);
```

Super confused. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What arguments are being passed to updateUserDb

Comment: the mongo user object and the facebook json response.

Comment: @YarGnawh this actually looks like correct usage except for res. Are you asking about how to pass `res`? Also +1 for clear question and synchronous exmample.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes. since `deferred.resolve()` can only pass one argument, `spread()` is the only option. i don't see how i can fulfill `handleResponse(res, user)`

Comment: slightly off-topic question... would it make sense to bind the `res` object to the promise at the beginning?  `Q.bind({ res: res }).when(....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `handleResponse` is expecting two params, but `updateUserDB` is only resolving a single object.  You could do something like:

```
function getResponseHandler(res) {
    return function(user) {
        // your handleResponse code here
        // which now has access to res
    }
}
```

and then call it like:

```
Q.all([getUserFromDB(userid), getUserProfileFromAPI(accessToken)])
 .spread(updateUserDB)
 .done(getResponseHandler(res));
```

Comment: It might be simpler to use a closure scope here.

Comment: @NG thanks for the example. how does the `user` object get passed to the `getResponseHandler(res)` ?

Comment: @YarGnawh the `getResponseHandler(res)` returns a function that receives the user object from `updateUserDB`.  That function also has access to the `res` object.

Comment: would returning that anonymous function "reset" the stack?